# Can you use the Spelljammer supplement for D&D 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, conversion, spelljammer

From what I have heard, [Spelljammer](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Spelljammer) sounds quite fun but it seems it was only released for 2e.
So does it just contain world descriptions or does it have new rules and if so, could they be converted to 5th edition Dungeons and Dragons?

Comment: I think we have some questions about converting 2e to 5e stuff, have you taken a look at them yet?

Comment: What do you mean by "could"? In principle, everything that has lore description can be rewritten to work with the new rules, except for the situation when new lore was created exactly to provide in-world explanation why rules changed, like it happens in Forgotten Realms quite regularly. Are you looking for an existing conversion or conversion guide?

Comment: I've got a session Friday that was wanting for a topic/pitch. Give me a week and I'll have a playtested answer for you =)

Comment: [Not an answer, but potentially helpful.](http://www.spelljammer.org/)

Comment: I'm concerned the “could it be converted” is a bit too vague, in that anything can be converted as long as you put in enough work. (It's already lead to one VLQ answer that more or less just says this as obvious.) If there's something more specific you can ask about than "is it possible to do it at all", I suggest you revise to ask about that.

Answer (score -4):

Yes.  You should be able to convert any content from previous editions into 5e.   The glory of 5e is the flexibility and lack of having super specific rules for every little thing, so go ahead and convert it as best you can.

you may find through play-testing that things need some tweaking, and then you may find that your tweaks need tweaking.

I encourage you to document your efforts of converting something like this, and share with the community.   You'll get more feedback than you want, and not all of it will be constructive, but some of it will help shape your idea into something that's possibly publishable somewhere like dmsguild or the like.